# Quoting multiple types of quotes

Tags: php, awk, quotes

Hi I have the following file:

```
$ cat file.txt
col1    col2    col3
zz2 mm  uu
pp3 yy  kk
ss2 tt  ll
zz3 mm  uu
pp23    yy  kk
ss3 tt  ll
ss3 aa  44
33c 22  99
```

I want to sort it using awk with the following unix command. This command sorts the tab file first on column1 and then on column2.

```
$ awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -t\"\t\" -k1 -k2"}' file.txt
```

and it works perfect.

```
$ awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -t\"\t\" -k1 -k2"}' file.txt
col1    col2    col3
33c 22  99
pp23    yy  kk
pp3 yy  kk
ss2 tt  ll
ss3 aa  44
ss3 tt  ll
zz2 mm  uu
zz3 mm  uu
```

My problem starts when I want to call it using Php as bash argument.

My code works fine if I call

```
print(shell_exec(/bin/bash -c "ls -l"))
```

Now I want to do the same for sorting command. Below is my php code:

```
$inpfile= 'file.txt';
$outfile= 'fileout.txt';
$bash = '/bin/bash ';
print(shell_exec($bash. " -c  \"ls -l\"")); print"<br />";

$command = 'awk \'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -t\"\t\" -k1 -k2" }\' '.$inpfile . " > " . $outfile; 
print("<br>". $command); //awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -t\"\t\" -k1 -k2" }' file.txt > fileout.txt

shell_exec($bash. " -c \"$command\""); //Gives error because of improper quotes. 
/*
$escaped = escapeshellarg($command);
$command1 = $bash. ' -c '.$escaped ; 
print("<br>". $command1);
//shell_exec($command1); 
*/
```

Help appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do it with a shell script? You could do this in PHP alone pretty easily, saving yourself the trouble of two languages.

Comment: Not really, I prefer awk as I guess it may be much faster. I have multiple files with large number of entries in it.

Comment: Ah that's fair enough. From your example given, I could see PHP being a better option, but yes, `awk` is faster for larger datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `/bin/bash` while using shell_exec function. You whole code can be cleaned up like this (**and it works fine**):

```
<?php
$inpfile= 'file.txt';
$outfile= 'fileout.txt';
$command = 'awk \'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -t\"\t\" -k1 -k2" }\' '
           . $inpfile . ' > ' . $outfile; 
var_dump($command);
shell_exec("$command"); // now works fine without any error
?>
```

Comment: In my system, php, by default calls sh. However I need bash to be called. and that is why I am using /bin/bash.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) and [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd)?

Comment: Yes, I tried different options but I failed as "\t" inside the command is creating a problem.